# Convergence in probability implies convergence in $L^2 $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Let $(X_n)_n$ a sequence of gaussian r.v. such that for any $m$ and $ n$
$(X_n − X_m)$ is gaussian.
If $X_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow X}$ then $X_n \overset{L^2}{\longrightarrow}X$ (more precisely in $ L^p ,\ p\in [1, +∞)$).

I tried to do this: convergence in probability implies convergence in law , and convergence in law of gaussians implies (Paul-Levy) that $ X \sim N(m,\sigma^2) $ with $m=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} m_n $ and $\sigma^2=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sigma^2_n$.
Convergence in probability also implies that the limit is a.s. unique.
Because $L^2$ is complete it is enough to prove that the sequence is Cauchy. Using the hypothesis :
$\int \lvert X_n-X_m \rvert^2 dP= \mathbb{E}[(X_n-X_m)^2]= (m_n-m_m)^2+(\sigma_n^2+\sigma_m^2)$
And i can find, fixed $\epsilon>0 , \hspace{0,3cm} n^* \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{0,3cm} $such that $\hspace{0,1cm} \forall m,n \geq n^*\hspace{0,4cm}  (m_n-m_m)^2+(\sigma_n^2+\sigma_m^2)<\epsilon \hspace{0,2cm}$ because of the limits above.

I would like to know where is the mistake and how i could fix it. I think i'm mistaken because the absolute moment equals the moment only if p is even, moreover it seems like i'm using convergence in probability only for the a.s. uniqueness of the limit. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your computation of $\mathbb E(X_n-X_m)^{2}$. It is not given that $X_n$ and $X_m$ are independent so it is not possible to compute this in terms of $m_n,m_m$ and $\sigma_n, \sigma_m$ at all!.

Here is a valid proof:   $X_n-X=\lim_{m \to \infty} (X_n-X_m)$ in probability. This implies that $X_n-X$ is Gaussian for each $n$. This, together with $X_n -X \to 0$ in probability implies that $\mathbb E(X_n-X)^{2} \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks! The hypothesis tells me that $(X_m-X_n)$ is gaussian and by linearity i can say that it's expected value and variance are the difference and sum of those respectively. If i call $Y=X_m-X_n$, knowing that it is a certain $N(m,\sigma^2)$  can't i use on $Y$ the formula for it's 2-order moment and substitute $m$ and $\sigma^2$ ?

Comment: There is no  problem with the mean but you cannot compute the second moment. We don't know what $E(X_nX_m)$ is.  @AndreaBaleani

Comment: @AndreaBaleani I have also added a valid proof.

Comment: Ok i got it, i mistakenly used that variance of the difference is the sum of the variances (but there's 2covariance also...). Thank you very much.